# Android build problem for a generated project - android.enableUnitTestBinaryResources deprecated

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I have strange problem while building a just generated Kotlin project with Android Studio.
I get this message:

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.application']
   > The option 'android.enableUnitTestBinaryResources' is deprecated.
     The current default is 'false'.
     It has been removed from the current version of the Android Gradle plugin.
     The raw resource for unit test functionality is removed.
```

I tried also IntelliJ with the same results. Restart/Invalidate cache and deleting .android directory also failed. The configuration:

- Android Studio 4.1.1
- Gradle Wrapper 6.5
- Project Android version R (11)
- compileSdkVersion 30
- buildToolsVersion 30.0.3

I'd appreciate any help and suggestions, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem. The property `android.enableUnitTestBinaryResources` was placed in global Gradle settings that the Gradle Wrapper had to source. After removing this property from `$HOME/.gradle/.gradle.properties` the builds started to work.